# What is an efficient way to serve images (PHP)?

Tags: php

Hey guys currently I am thinking of serving images using an image handler script. I have two sources of images. One is from my web images folder where images that are used to construct my site interface are served. The other is in each users images folder where they can store their own images. I was thinking of giving each user image a unique id and then searching that id with the image handler script and serving the image, and changing the file name. The problem is that my site images folder does not have any information in the database and thus has no ids, should I just serve directly? Also this way of serving user images does not seem like the most efficient. If anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

```
$sql="SELECT username,file_name FROM images WHERE id=?";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute(array($ID));

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$image_name = $row['file_name'];
$username = $row['username'];
}

$path="$username/images/$image_name";


header("Expires: -1");

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");

header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);

readfile($path);
```

Comment: You should add some error handling to your script. What if no record or the corresponding file is not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious efficient way it to forgo PHP and let it be served directly by Apache, with caching. Is there any reason you have to keep track of images in this way you can't do with just parsing access_log's after the fact? And why no caching, I assume a new image gets a new unique id, not a rehashed old one?

That being said: if you do need database retrieval & serve it with php, it is about as efficient as you can get, although be very war of folders named by usernames, a possible security issue. Maybe cache the query result somewhere in memcached or the like, that's about it.

Comment: Add: @Matthew Flaschen's remark about a static only server is indeed a good one if stretched for resources. Even on the same server a seperate LightHTTPD  or Apache process (stripped of all the modules) can make a lot of difference.

Comment: so basically do what I am doing? What would you recommend doing for web site images like buttons and such where there is no database information should I serve directly from folder without handler?

Comment: @Scarface, I think that it's worth mentioning the nginx server. You can use it as a reverse proxy, so it will serve all static web site images and your apache server won't even know that the user has requested them.

Comment: @Scarface yes, serve without handler, actually as said, preferably serve with a server without cgi/modules handler entirely. If not going the separate server route, possibly serve at least user-uploaded files from a non-interpreted folder (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#removehandler)

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient way to serve images is to have them all on a separate static-only [cookie-free domain](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free).  This is how sites like Flickr work.  All you need to store in the database is enough info to construct the static URL.

Comment: That is what I figured, but given that I do not have this capability yet, would you recommend serving each image in the fashion I am doing, and how should I served my web site images like the header and buttons?

Comment: It doesn't actually have to be a separate physical server.  A second virtual host is more than sufficient.

Comment: @Scarface, I would definitely not run all static content through PHP.  Frank is right that you can use a separate virtual host even if you only have one physical server.

Comment: I only have the resources for one virtual account right now, I do not run my own server, I am with a provider. Your idea is great, but I simply need to cope with what I have for now, given my site is in really early stages and does not receive many requests yet. If you do not recommend running images (static content) through php, what is a secure way to serve images?

Comment: If it is direct then isn't that a security risk?

Comment: @Scar, probably not.  If you use a random path then the content shouldn't be accessible unless the user shares the URL.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to serve images is to not use PHP at all.

Let your web server serve images directly from disk.  They end up cached in memory by Linux anyway, so it's really fast.  Several times faster than anything you can possibly do in PHP.  Load up firebug and try it yourself.  Watch how long it takes for apache to return an image from disk, versus from your script (I did a year ago, with a similar script that used `readfile()`).  The difference is significant.  If you run a load tester like ab or httperf you'll probably see an even larger difference in requests per second.

There's always X-Sendfile too, which some http servers support.

Alternately, consider putting a caching reverse proxy like varnish in front of your script, so that you're at least

Comment: I was originally doing directly from disk but I want to make it harder for bots and malicious users to find this content and download all of it which would put a strain on my server so I thought of just mixing up file names and serving from php script so the directory is not displayed. Could your way protect from this?

Comment: could you maybe put an example, I am not exactly sure what you mean

Comment: nginx, lighttpd, and varnish can all serve thousands of image requests per second without putting a strain on your server.  If anything, I'd be more concerned about bandwidth.  How exactly do you expect a php script to prevent bots from requesting your images?  image.php?id=123 is just as easy to request as /images/123.jpg

Comment: yes but the image file name is found based on its id, the image name is not know to the user because it is changed. The id does not equal the name. I currently am running apache, wouldn't I need a separate virtual host or server to run lighttpd or nginx? That is not really an option right now.

Comment: I just want a secure and fairly efficient way of serving files because I was told if served directly can be a security liability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what your problem is but, in your templates, instead of:

```
<img src="image_handler.php?id=123" />
```

you should write:

```
<?php
    $file_data = get_file_data(123);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $file_data['user_name'], "/images/", $file_data['image_name']; ?>" />
```

And don't forget to escape your data.

You should not serve your files with PHP. Moreover, you should find a webhost that offers you Apache **and** lighttpd or nginx. Apache is not very fast when it comes to serving static files.